# Avoiding double counting in pandas merge

Tags: python, pandas

Problem 1:

I have aggregated two large (for me) files which date back to January 2014. One is 17 mil rows and the other is about 3 mil rows. I aggregated them based on the Date field the PersonID field, and the CustomerID field and summed up a column which is just 1 per row.

File 1 (I dropped duplicates so a PersonID should only have 1 visit per CustomerID per Date):

```
Date | PersonID | CustomerID | Sum of Visits
```

File 2 (this does not have a complete record of CustomerID so I am not including it - I want the total Chats first so I do not leave out such a large chunk of data):

```
Date | PersonID | Sum of Chats
```

When I do a pd.merge(file1, file2, how= 'left') I end up severely increasing the number of chats from file 2. This is because the PersonID might have several CustomerIDs on the same Date so if they had multiple chats it is adding those chats for each row. This does not work out well when I load the data in Tableau and sum it up. (The end result I am looking for is dividing the total Visits by the total Chats for each PersonID to create a ratio). What's the best approach here?

Problem 2:

After I finish the aggregated files I want to again merge the two files at the granular row level. My issue is that File 2 can really have multiple Chats for the same PersonID on the same Date. Is there a way to join/merge this with File 1 which only has one record per PersonID+Date+CustomerID without creating duplicate Visits on the first file?

File 2 :

```
Date | PersonID | CustomerID | Count of Chat
```

Comment: +1 for a good question. However, some clarity is needed: Why would you drop duplicates in File 1 to leave only 1 visit per CustomerID per date? That would mean that the `Sum of Visits` column is misleading because it's not going to show you the sum, only ones, yes? An alternative is pivoting File 1 to show you the actual sum of visits per PersonID. You don't need the CustomerID to do a sum of visit versus sum of chats ratio anyway. If the data is not overly sensitive, maybe you can provide a hundred rows each of the raw data, upload it somewhere, and I'll have a look over it for you.

Comment: The File 1 data is not so accurate,  users input the data which means that sometimes there are like 10 timestamps for the same CustomerID which is not possible. The only way I could clean it was to drop the duplicates. About 340k out of 17 mil. I do sum Visits after I groupby and it does calculate correctly. Yeah perhaps I'll drop the CustomerID for now..  I wanted it because it includes geographic information which I use to place in maps on tableau. I can add that later perhaps.  On phone now but I'll try to upload data later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming my vision of your data is close, see my approach.

First, reproducible data.

```
In [2]: d1 = {'Date': {0: pd.Timestamp('2010-01-01 00:00:00'), 1: pd.Timestamp('2010-01-02 00:00:00'), 2: pd.Timestamp('2010-01-03 00:00:00'), 3: pd.Timestamp('2010-01-03 00:00:00'), 4: pd.Timestamp('2010-01-03 00:00:00'), 5: pd.Timestamp('2010-01-06 00:00:00'), 6: pd.Timestamp('2010-01-06 00:00:00'), 7: pd.Timestamp('2010-01-06 00:00:00'), 8: pd.Timestamp('2010-01-09 00:00:00'), 9: pd.Timestamp('2010-01-10 00:00:00'), 10: pd.Timestamp('2010-01-11 00:00:00'), 11: pd.Timestamp('2010-01-12 00:00:00'), 12: pd.Timestamp('2010-01-12 00:00:00'), 13: pd.Timestamp('2010-01-12 00:00:00'), 14: pd.Timestamp('2010-01-12 00:00:00'), 15: pd.Timestamp('2010-01-12 00:00:00'), 16: pd.Timestamp('2010-01-17 00:00:00'), 17: pd.Timestamp('2010-01-17 00:00:00'), 18: pd.Timestamp('2010-01-17 00:00:00'), 19: pd.Timestamp('2010-01-17 00:00:00')}, 'PersonID': {0: 'Foo', 1: 'Bar', 2: 'Foo', 3: 'Bar', 4: 'Foo', 5: 'Bar', 6: 'Foo', 7: 'Bar', 8: 'Foo', 9: 'Bar', 10: 'Foo', 11: 'Bar', 12: 'Foo', 13: 'Bar', 14: 'Foo', 15: 'Bar', 16: 'Foo', 17: 'Bar', 18: 'Foo', 19: 'Bar'}, 'CustomerID': {0: 'aaa', 1: 'bbb', 2: 'ccc', 3: 'ddd', 4: 'eee', 5: 'fff', 6: 'ggg', 7: 'hhh', 8: 'iii', 9: 'jjj', 10: 'kkk', 11: 'lll', 12: 'mmm', 13: 'nnn', 14: 'ooo', 15: 'ppp', 16: 'qqq', 17: 'rrr', 18: 'sss', 19: 'ttt'}}
   ...: 
   ...: d2 = {'Date': {0: pd.Timestamp('2010-01-01 00:00:00'), 1: pd.Timestamp('2010-01-02 00:00:00'), 2: pd.Timestamp('2010-01-03 00:00:00'), 3: pd.Timestamp('2010-01-06 00:00:00'), 4: pd.Timestamp('2010-01-09 00:00:00'), 5: pd.Timestamp('2010-01-10 00:00:00'), 6: pd.Timestamp('2010-01-11 00:00:00'), 7: pd.Timestamp('2010-01-12 00:00:00'), 8: pd.Timestamp('2010-01-17 00:00:00'), 9: pd.Timestamp('2010-01-01 00:00:00'), 10: pd.Timestamp('2010-01-02 00:00:00'), 11: pd.Timestamp('2010-01-03 00:00:00'), 12: pd.Timestamp('2010-01-06 00:00:00'), 13: pd.Timestamp('2010-01-09 00:00:00'), 14: pd.Timestamp('2010-01-10 00:00:00'), 15: pd.Timestamp('2010-01-11 00:00:00'), 16: pd.Timestamp('2010-01-12 00:00:00'), 17: pd.Timestamp('2010-01-17 00:00:00')}, 'PersonID': {0: 'Foo', 1: 'Foo', 2: 'Foo', 3: 'Foo', 4: 'Foo', 5: 'Foo', 6: 'Foo', 7: 'Foo', 8: 'Foo', 9: 'Bar', 10: 'Bar', 11: 'Bar', 12: 'Bar', 13: 'Bar', 14: 'Bar', 15: 'Bar', 16: 'Bar', 17: 'Bar'}, 'Sum of Chats': {0: 5.0, 1: 3.0, 2: 24.0, 3: 7.0, 4: 15.0, 5: 9.0, 6: 16.0, 7: 22.0, 8: 14.0, 9: 8.0, 10: 15.0, 11: 14.0, 12: 29.0, 13: 11.0, 14: 6.0, 15: 14.0, 16: 30.0, 17: 12.0}}

In [3]: df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d1)
   ...: df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d2)
```

The above produces the following dataframes.

```
# File 1

   CustomerID       Date PersonID
0         aaa 2010-01-01      Foo
1         bbb 2010-01-02      Bar
2         ccc 2010-01-03      Foo
3         ddd 2010-01-03      Bar
4         eee 2010-01-03      Foo
5         fff 2010-01-06      Bar
6         ggg 2010-01-06      Foo
7         hhh 2010-01-06      Bar
8         iii 2010-01-09      Foo
9         jjj 2010-01-10      Bar
10        kkk 2010-01-11      Foo
11        lll 2010-01-12      Bar
12        mmm 2010-01-12      Foo
13        nnn 2010-01-12      Bar
14        ooo 2010-01-12      Foo
15        ppp 2010-01-12      Bar
16        qqq 2010-01-17      Foo
17        rrr 2010-01-17      Bar
18        sss 2010-01-17      Foo
19        ttt 2010-01-17      Bar

# File 2

         Date PersonID  Sum of Chats
0  2010-01-01      Foo             5
1  2010-01-02      Foo             3
2  2010-01-03      Foo            24
3  2010-01-06      Foo             7
4  2010-01-09      Foo            15
5  2010-01-10      Foo             9
6  2010-01-11      Foo            16
7  2010-01-12      Foo            22
8  2010-01-17      Foo            14
9  2010-01-01      Bar             8
10 2010-01-02      Bar            15
11 2010-01-03      Bar            14
12 2010-01-06      Bar            29
13 2010-01-09      Bar            11
14 2010-01-10      Bar             6
15 2010-01-11      Bar            14
16 2010-01-12      Bar            30
17 2010-01-17      Bar            12
```

If, by any chance, you want to use the `CustomerID` to count the visits, you can use `pivot_table` to aggregate it really quickly.

```
In [4]: df1 = df1.pivot_table(index=['Date','PersonID'], values='CustomerID', aggfunc=len)
   ...: print df1
Date        PersonID
2010-01-01  Foo         1
2010-01-02  Bar         1
2010-01-03  Bar         1
            Foo         2
2010-01-06  Bar         2
            Foo         1
2010-01-09  Foo         1
2010-01-10  Bar         1
2010-01-11  Foo         1
2010-01-12  Bar         3
            Foo         2
2010-01-17  Bar         2
            Foo         2
Name: CustomerID, dtype: int64
```

I prefer to combine this with `reset_index` when aggregating instead of other approaches because I am afforded the above sneak-peek of meaningful data while pivoting.

```
In [5]: df1 = df1.reset_index(); print df1
         Date PersonID  CustomerID
0  2010-01-01      Foo           1
1  2010-01-02      Bar           1
2  2010-01-03      Bar           1
3  2010-01-03      Foo           2
4  2010-01-06      Bar           2
5  2010-01-06      Foo           1
6  2010-01-09      Foo           1
7  2010-01-10      Bar           1
8  2010-01-11      Foo           1
9  2010-01-12      Bar           3
10 2010-01-12      Foo           2
11 2010-01-17      Bar           2
12 2010-01-17      Foo           2
```

So we're pretty much at the start. Remaining step would be to merge it with the second dataframe to get our chats per date per person.

```
In [6]: df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', sort=True)
   ...: print df
         Date PersonID  CustomerID  Sum of Chats
0  2010-01-01      Bar         NaN             8
1  2010-01-01      Foo           1             5
2  2010-01-02      Bar           1            15
3  2010-01-02      Foo         NaN             3
4  2010-01-03      Bar           1            14
5  2010-01-03      Foo           2            24
6  2010-01-06      Bar           2            29
7  2010-01-06      Foo           1             7
8  2010-01-09      Bar         NaN            11
9  2010-01-09      Foo           1            15
10 2010-01-10      Bar           1             6
11 2010-01-10      Foo         NaN             9
12 2010-01-11      Bar         NaN            14
13 2010-01-11      Foo           1            16
14 2010-01-12      Bar           3            30
15 2010-01-12      Foo           2            22
16 2010-01-17      Bar           2            12
17 2010-01-17      Foo           2            14
```

Granted, the NaNs are a product of faulty mock data set-up on my part. From here, it's just straight-up calculations.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: There are several new approaches here in this answer that I have not tried. Is this better to do on the row based file (meaning I should not do groupby first)?  When you do the aggfunction Len,  why do you do it that way?  Before I was doing groupby as index = false  then .aggregate sum on visits or chats. Thanks for your insight so far

Comment: `groupby` has the downside of introducing iterables. It's easy to set-up, but it takes some time to get used to. Coming from an Excel-reliant environment, I crunch numbers quickly using pivot tables, which `pandas` executes in much better ways. `aggfunc` is similar to Excel's `View values as` option, and feeding it `len` is similar to using `Count` in Excel's pivot table. Granted, the syntax for `pivot_table` takes some getting used to due to its relative strictness compared to the other `pandas` functions, but it can manipulate AND show meaningful data at the same time.